# Fetch data from external website not using web services

Tags: asp.net, fetch

In my application, I have an ASP.Net web page with a textbox and a button control. The requirement is that on click of the button, I need to fetch some data from an external website based on the value entered in the textbox.

Note that there is no web service or API provided by the external website. The website has a page with a form that provides similar functionality. I cannot load the external web page inside my application as it has a lot of irrelevant content as well.

Can someone help with thoughts on how I can achieve this requirement, if not via web services?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is getting the entire website with a `WebRequest`. You then have the enire page as HTML in a string. You can do a search in that string for the information you need.

```
string responseString = string.Empty;

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.nl");

try
{
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException wex)
{
}
```